# Impossible Python login with Requests library

Tags: python, html, http, python-requests

I'm trying to log in to my university's e-book library website with Python using Requests, but I can't get it to work. Here's the website: https://dliportal.zbra.com.br/Login.aspx?key=facamp

I'll try to explain what I already tried to do, and how the website reacts to the browser. **I'd really appreciate if someone could help me solve this problem**.

First, the website's HTML form:

---

## GET response data (dliportal.zbra.com.br)

### Website's HTML form

```html
<form method="post" action="./Login.aspx?key=facamp" id="form1">
  <div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="C2EE9ABB" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAARagD/5Vf04/C/8v8SJMNZdjiw86D7eNbSVjVVvFunipFwgSqpCSL2Tos3TZ5JWb9vOzLf+PULXAx0siEaqrIWOgTSIXBJ5uo+c7a8pkO6cT0yZ6wM=" />
  </div>
  <div id="loginPanel" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;loginButton&#39;)">

    <div class="error">

    </div>
    <div class="label">
      Usu&#225;rio
    </div>
    <input name="userIdTextBox" type="text" id="userIdTextBox" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="label">
      Senha
    </div>
    <input name="passwordTextBox" type="password" id="passwordTextBox" />
    <input type="submit" name="loginButton" value="Enviar" onclick="onLoginButtonClick();" id="loginButton" class="loginButton" />

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
    if (!theForm) {
      theForm = document.form1;
    }

    function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
      if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
      }
    }
    //]]>
  </script>


  <script src="/WebResource.axd?d=hkoRzRlCWRL1gDTxkMTECkL0SdnTFKsR85ScXniT89wsyTQr3BXlegfier9ueW4imHFUF8V7SadD_ZSL_a4tRk9NoJ81&amp;t=636372397539900582" type="text/javascript"></script>
</form>
```

---

There are a lot of *input* tags, and checking Network Monitor on Chrome after login, I noticed that "__VIEWSTATE", "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", "__EVENTTARGET", "__EVENTARGUMENT", "__EVENTVALIDATION", as well as my credencials in "userIdTextBox" and "passwordTextBox" are sent with a POST request using the values from html's form:

---

## POST data (dliportal.zbra.com.br)

```
**General**
    Request URL:https://dliportal.zbra.com.br/Login.aspx?key=facamp
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:302 Found
    Remote Address:104.41.44.15:443
    Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Response Headers**
    Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600
    Content-Length:7295
    Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
    Date:Mon, 04 Sep 2017 21:49:31 GMT
    Expires:Mon, 04 Sep 2017 22:49:30 GMT
    Last-Modified:Mon, 04 Sep 2017 21:49:30 GMT
    Location:https://sso.vitalsource.com/auth/redirects/[a_long_string_here]
    Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
    Vary:*
    X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

**Request Headers**
    Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
    Cache-Control:max-age=0
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:1126
    Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=10xulosmwzxsxhbkqfnqupwy; _ga=GA1.3.982569079.1504561026; _gid=GA1.3.1369811403.1504561026; _gat=1
    Host:dliportal.zbra.com.br
    Origin:https://dliportal.zbra.com.br
    Referer:https://dliportal.zbra.com.br/Login.aspx?key=facamp
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36

**Query String Parameters**
    key:facamp

**Form Data**
    __VIEWSTATE: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
    __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:C2EE9ABB
    __EVENTTARGET:loginButton
    __EVENTARGUMENT:
    __EVENTVALIDATION:/wEdAARagD/5Vf04/C/8v8SJMNZdjiw86D7eNbSVjVVvFunipFwgSqpCSL2Tos3TZ5JWb9vOzLf+PULXAx0siEaqrIWOgTSIXBJ5uo+c7a8pkO6cT0yZ6wM=
    userIdTextBox:--myUsername--
    passwordTextBox:--myPassword--
    loginButton:Enviar
```

---

Please notice the "Location" entry under Response Headers. It leads the browser to another URL: [https://sso.vitalsource.com/auth/redirects/[a_long_string_here]](https://sso.vitalsource.com/auth/redirects/%5Ba_long_string_here%5D).

So far so good, I could perfectly reproduce this behavior via Requests library with the following code:

---

## My Python Code

```
import requests, bs4

url = 'https://dliportal.zbra.com.br/Login.aspx?key=facamp'
userA = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0'
cred = {'userIdTextBox':'--myUsername--', 'passwordTextBox':'--myPassword--'}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers['User-Agent'] = userA

r1 = s.get(url)

# Generate HTTP request's body extracting CSRF data from HTML's form
r1 = s.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r1.text, 'html.parser')
vbody = {}
for elem in soup.form.findAll('input'):
    if 'value' in elem.attrs.keys():
        vbody[elem['name']] = elem['value']
    else:
        vbody[elem['name']] = cred[elem['name']]

r2 = s.post(url, data=vbody)
print(r2.url, '->', r2.status_code, r2.reason)

# https://sso.vitalsource.com/auth/redirects/[a_long_string_here] -> 401 Unauthorized
```

---

As you can see on the last code comment, it redirects me to the right website, but I get code 401 Unauthorized. If I login via browser, here's the GET request to the former website:

---

## GET data (sso.vitalsource.com)

```
**General**
    Request URL:https://sso.vitalsource.com/auth/redirects/NTVV35ZSFJ3M74GZDBKHWGZ7BUSYMRBCEFZHDFAUTKB7T4EM4C
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:302 Found
    Remote Address:198.183.167.120:443
    Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Response Headers**
    Cache-Control:no-cache
    Connection:Keep-Alive
    Content-Encoding:gzip
    Content-Length:113
    Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
    Date:Mon, 04 Sep 2017 21:49:33 GMT
    Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=411
    Location:https://integrada.minhabiblioteca.com.br/books/
    P3P:CP="ALL DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND COM NAV"
    Served-By:lvvsboappp08.vitalbook.com
    Server:Apache
    Set-Cookie:_jigsaw_session=bWhIMGtyVXhidmxybTFLdDVRclRRclRxTEdGc1ZFZGdlTFJkWUF0T3JYYjFaWERJcHl2eWJWS21YYlNQL1hwcGhnRks5SDU5cjloSExMaHhXeGlMalFMQzRyVnc4ZFUvSzJQM1UzSXRmWnFtUVlNNTlGNVZuOWhDeUdveUorcitBYVFicVFIT0xlUHRPdGkzd3lGR0pBRXlxZG45OWhQVmdjbDgvWFBSWEtMYUlpZnJYN2lORlo4QWNDckVzcU9PakI1SDNMa1VCd2FVVlcrcTNhUGVmSHN2SnZkdEJGUnRKWEdwamRQR3JEQT0tLXRKL2Z3TE8vcklHUkVXcmp0SXpxNXc9PQ%3D%3D--c0e95c8c387a31ed93c406be8b1e42569b8c7000; path=/; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie:bookshelf_signin_services=WHBS5F3VDXWHFZHYV7SVDJWJF43F4ERRD6F6Y56ACNJTSX6P6F; domain=vitalsource.com; path=/; expires=Mon, 04 Sep 2017 21:54:33 -0000
    Set-Cookie:doorman-bookshelf_signin-services=WHBS5F3VDXWHFZHYV7SVDJWJF43F4ERRD6F6Y56ACNJTSX6P6F; domain=vitalsource.com; path=/; expires=Mon, 04 Sep 2017 21:54:33 -0000
    Status:302 Found
    Vary:Accept-Encoding
    X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
    X-Powered-By:Phusion Passenger 4.0.59
    X-Request-Id:38ac3ad5-8270-4088-96b4-0be67b4cc941
    X-Runtime:0.063307
    X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block

**Request Headers**
    Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
    Cache-Control:max-age=0
    Connection:keep-alive
    Host:sso.vitalsource.com
    Referer:https://dliportal.zbra.com.br/Login.aspx?key=facamp
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
```

---

Notice that it's sending no cookie under "Request Headers", or any other piece of relevant information. I have no idea why it's not working. Could it possibly be because of the javascript present on the first webpage HTML?

**Please, I'd really appreciate if someone could help me solve this problem**. I can send any further information in detail if needed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try with `s.headers['Referer'] = url`.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work, still getting code 401.

Comment: have you tried disabling js in your browser and see if you could login ?

Comment: Tried disabling javascript and could login just fine, but there is a difference:
with js disabled, the **GET data (sso.vitalsource.com)** sends 3 cookies under "Request Headers", called "_jigsaw_session", "bookshelf_signin_services" and "doorman-bookshelf_signin-services". These cookies have not been set by any prior request/response, I don't know where it came from.

---

sso.vitalsource.com responded the GET request with 3 cookies with the same name as the ones requested, but with different values.

Comment: What are we missing? It's really strange.

Comment: Try `vbody['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'loginButton'`

Comment: Tried, still getting code 401.

It's driving me insane, how can it not work? I'm perfectly mimicing the requests sent by the browser... (Ain't I?)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you move on to `selenium`
This way you can emulate a real web browser which will be able to work with javascript.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: I'd really like to be able to do it with Requests library, for learning purposes... It should work, right? If the browser can do it, I should be able to reproduce its behavior via Requests, considering that I can login even with javascript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

you should use fiddler to capture packet,because chrome don't do well in capture packet in capturing redirect action.
'sso.vitalsource.com' is a redirect url. if may contain some html or js content.
it is very necessary to capture packet and analyze before you edit scraping code.

Comment: I'll try to use Fiddler... Are there any "special" config I need to setup for this purpose? It's not showing GET requests

Comment: you should see some tutorial about fiddler.

Comment: i  know how you request works.  https://sso.vitalsource.com/auth/redirects/[a_long_string_here]  ,the page give this request,is a redirect page, the long_string is  included in this page,maybe the long_string is a sessionId or part of sessionId.  i  have done several  login simulation  by using requests like this.

Comment: It would be really good if you could detail the process you've done to successfully log in with this kind of requests; I'd really apreciate it. A little more detail from what's happening: this sso.vitalsource.com page is a "Location Header" response from a successfull POST request sent to https://dliportal.zbra.com.br/Login.aspx?key=facamp; but when i try to GET the page (with the "long_string" provided), it returns code 401.

Comment: the data you use to request  sso.vitalsource.com/auth/redirects/[a_long_string_here]  is wrong.                            first ,you should use get to request sso.vitalsource.com/auth/redirects/[a_long_string_here], second, why you know the long_string is input .  i don't have a account to login  sucessfully,so i don't know the whole process.  i suggest you spend more time to capture packet and analyse packet.  can you show me  the response afte  https://dliportal.zbra.com.br/Login.aspx?key=facamp login successful.the url and the long_string should be included in this response.

Comment: sso.vitalsource.com/auth/redirects/[a_long_string_here]  is a  request that use get way. the long_string should be inculded  in you login request's response .  you should print the post login request's response.

Comment: if you are not used to using fiddler,you can print  r.content or r.text  to know the response.

Comment: Yeah I know that... I'm not trying to login to "/[a_long_string_here]", this was just a way to post it here on stack overflow with a shorter URL. I'm actually trying to login to the value returned by the POST request which I send to the login's form "action" parameter (see HTML). When I send the data, it returns a URL, with the "long_string" included. But when I try to GET this page, it returns code 401